# In ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC Project, How exactly do I log to app insights using ilogger?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to determine how exactly to log to app insights using

```
_logger.LogInformation
```

Im not finding the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core very helpful.

For example, lets imagine you create an asp.net core **3.0** MVC project using visual studio (template)
By default, the controller has injected _logger.

What exact step-by-steps are required to get the logger to send the data to app insights? Any help is appreciated. 
 I just am hoping to know which files exactly I need to update in the project.

Comment: Check this out https://blog.techfabric.io/using-application-insights/

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, thats for 2.1? Im looking for dotnet core 3.0

Comment: @joey Which version of nuget package "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" are you using? You should try version 2.8.0 or higher.

Comment: @ivan, can you please post an answer with the exact steps necessary?including the package reference?

Comment: @joey, please let me know if you have more issues after the answer below :).

Comment: Thank you @IvanYang, very good answer. This is very helpful to me and hopefully to the broader community. I appreciate your post!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#ilogger-logs There is no need to do anything additional to capture ilogger logs. Follow the doc as such and you should see all Warning or above level logs captured automatically.

Comment: @cijothomas, you mention that using the above doc, only Warning or above. Would that mean your solution would then be to update the logging level in appsetting.env.json to information? Would that be a better answer you can provide below? It really sounds like an alternative answer to the question since specifically I'm looking for logger.LogInformation?

Comment: You can control logging level by modifying appsettings.json. Its documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

You can control it by setting proper loglevel in appsettings.json file -> adding `ApplicationInsights section`, without any code change(for .net core 3.0, please use [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/2.8.0) package 2.8.0 version or higher, the notes is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#supported-scenarios)).

Here is the my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Then `LogInformation()` method can work well.

Comment: `loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights()` is obsolete. There is no need to any additional step to capture Ilogger logs as its automatically enabled when adding ApplicationInsights using Visual Studio (or manually by adding services.AddApplicationInsights()).

Comment: Can you update the full answer to not have any extraneous details? It looked like you had updated it but there was still the older reference? Just trying to find the bare minimum to get log information working. Perhaps just to update the appsettings.env.json file logging setting?

Comment: is it possible to use log.loginformation with just an update to appsettings.env.json and little code changes? It sounds like thats the alternative way you are talking about adding perhaps an answer for as well?

Comment: @joey, I find it's possible just change appsettings.json. It's my bad, I add the loglevel to a wrong place. I have updated the post remove extra steps.

Comment: @cijothomas, you're correct, I tried it before, but add the loglevel to a wrong place. I have updated my post, thank you for pointing it out:)